# PHP global function and class with same name

Tags: php

This works in PHP:

```
class Foo{
  ....
}

function Foo(){return new Foo();}
```

Is that a safe/advisable practice in PHP? (in the sense that it may cause troubles now or in future versions)

The reason to use this is somehow to make code clearer in a way like this:

```
class Foo{
   var $bar,$hold;
   function setBar($how=true){$bar=$how;return $this;}
   function setHold($how=true){$hold=$how;return $this;}
}
function Foo(){return new Foo();}
//------------------

$someFoo=Foo()->setBar()->setHold(false);
// instead of $someFoo=(new Foo())->setBar()->setHold(false);
```

that might make the code more readable and/or save some typing.

Comment: Generally speaking, your code should be as clear as possible. Having a class and function with the same name is confusing. I would avoid doing this if at all possible

Comment: it might work, but it's probably going to cause confusion, especially if anyone else has to read it. That would apply in almost any language, not just PHP.

Comment: I can reuse identifiers for different types in all languages I know so I can't imagine a reason why a future PHP version would eventually disallow it. In any case, although PHP releases break things inadvertently now and then they keep an excellent backwards compatibility record when it comes to the language syntax.

Comment: As about your edit, if I go in that line I'd prefer `$someFoo  = MakeFoo()->setBar()->setHold(false);` or, even better, implement the Builder design pattern.